# Rails AJAX with Bootstrap Collapse, don't make method invocation on toggle-close

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion collapse section, which works just fine. Each list item in the accordion links_to a certain method, which is called via AJAX. The controller responds appropriately with javascript, calls a ____.js.erb file, which renders a partial inside the div that is correlated with the collapse list item. All of this works just fine.

To close the collapse section, the user is required to click the top level list item a second time, which they clicked once to open it. This is all within the bootstrap defaults. However, when the user clicks that list item a second time, since I've linked that item remotely to a controller method, the server is hit a second time, when all I really want is for the collapse section to disappear. This doesn't really cause an error per say, it's more just like undesired behavior.

Is there some way to achieve this(where a second click that would close the collapse section doesn't actually make a server method invocation)? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a general outline of my code flow:

View with Accoridion:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<% @fantasy_players.each do |fantasy_player| %>
    <%= render partial: 'leagues_and_teams/teams/fantasy_player', locals: {fantasy_player: fantasy_player} %>
<% end %>
```

Partial that is called above:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" role="tab">
    <div class="media">
        <%= image_tag fantasy_player.player.avatar.url(:small) %>
        <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <%= link_to fantasy_player.player.name, players_and_stats_player_card_path(player_id: fantasy_player.player.id), remote: true, :"role" => "tabpanel", :"data-toggle" => "collapse", :"data-parent" => "#accordion" %>
        </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="team_fantasy_player_<%= fantasy_player.player.id %>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel"></div>
</div>
```

...which then hits the controller etc.

Thank you!